# Como compartilhar um texto no facebook sem ter o aplicativo instalado no Android?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk

Preciso compartilhar um texto e uma imagem no facebook. Na net tem muitos tutoriais que precisam ter o app do facebook instalado. Alguém tem algum tutorial de como fazer isso sem ter o facebook no Android? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Esse trecho de código compartilha no facebook sem ter necessariamente o app instalado, ele verifica se tem o app, se não tiver ele compartilha, mas nesse caso ele ta compartilhando um Link, espero que as validações que verificam se tem o app te ajudem!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);
// See if official Facebook app is found
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
     if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook")){
          intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
          facebookAppFound = true;
          break;  
     }
}
// As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
if (!facebookAppFound) {
     String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" +              urlToShare;
     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Fonte:[share without facebook app installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627295/how-to-share-a-link-to-facebook-without-facebook-app-installed)